# How can I set multiple notifications in my android app?

Tags: android, notifications

I have just added the notification feature in my android app, but now I'm looking for multiple notifications from that very application, say in a repetitive period of about 15 minutes..

Comment: English please... And I am not sure what you are asking. Somehow I find title and question opposites.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire multiple notifications from your app whenever you want, but the user's won't be too happy with it, so use it wisely